# Value not return to calling method when using ConsumerRecord<> in the listner

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

## KafkaListener

```
  @KafkaListener(id = ProductTopicConstants.UPDATE_PRODUCT, topics = ProductTopicConstants.UPDATE_PRODUCT,
            containerFactory = "addUpdateProductContainerFactory")
    @SendTo
    public Object UpdateProduct(ConsumerRecord<String, ProductViewModel> productViewModel) {
        String id = productViewModel.key();
        Product product = productRepository.findByid(id);
        if (product != null) {
            product.setName(productViewModel.name());
            product.setPrice(productViewModel.price());
            product.setDescription(productViewModel.description());
            return productRepository.save(product);
        }
        return KafkaNull.INSTANCE;
    }
```

## Producer

```
   public GenericResponse<ProductViewModel> Update(ProductViewModel product, String id) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, Object> future =
                this._replyTemplate.sendAndReceive(new ProducerRecord<>(ProductTopicConstants.UPDATE_PRODUCT,0, id,product));
        LOG.info(future.getSendFuture().get(kafkaConstants.kafkaTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS).getRecordMetadata().toString());
        Object productDb = future.get(kafkaConstants.kafkaTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS).value();
        if (productDb == null)
            return null;
        if (productDb == HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
            return new GenericResponse<ProductViewModel>(null, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        Product mappedProducts = mapper.convertValue(productDb, new TypeReference<Product>() {});
        return new GenericResponse<ProductViewModel>(new ProductViewModel(mappedProducts.getId(), mappedProducts.getName(), mappedProducts.getPrice(), mappedProducts.getDescription(), mappedProducts.getVersion()), null);

    }
```

## Container configuration

```
   @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, ProductViewModel> consumerFactoryAddUpdateProduct() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(),
                new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(ProductViewModel.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> addUpdateProductContainerFactory(ProducerFactory<String, Object> pf) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ProductViewModel> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryAddUpdateProduct());
        factory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate(pf));
        return factory;
    }
```

## Error

```
org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.KafkaReplyTimeoutException: Reply timed out
    at org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.ReplyingKafkaTemplate.lambda$scheduleTimeout$3(ReplyingKafkaTemplate.java:339) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: either it could be th4e kafka is not up or the port is wrong.

Comment: Nope kafka is running, connection to kafka is fine

Comment: can you increase the reply time out to something more

Comment: Nope increasing the timeout doesn't work as @Gary has mention in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem; I am working on solution; the request/reply processing is based on spring-messaging; when you consume the raw `ConsumerRecord`, the reply handing doesn't work because the messaging logic is bypassed.

The work around is to change the method to `public Object UpdateProduct(Message<ProductViewModel> message)` instead.

The headers are contained in `message.getHeaders()`, the key is in header `KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY`.

The `ProductViewModel` is `message.getPayload()`.